# Force docker to wait for a specific container during docker-compose restart

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have container A and B, when I do `docker-compose restart` I want it to start container A first and then container B. I specified the `depends_on` directive, but it seems to be ignored (I see it starting up container B first).

Running version 3.4 of the YML file which has 2 services (A, B).

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`depends_on` only waits, until a container has the state `running`, not until it is `ready`. See the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) on how to wait until a container is "ready".

Comment: excellent, thank you for the clarifications!